# Images inside a grid are not scaling with viewport

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If I place images inside a CSS grid i.e. if imgs act as grid items than they are not scaling with viewport which would happen otherwise. (These are just 4 equally sized images)

```
.imgContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 196px 196px;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imgContainer img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: @TannerDolby, there was nothing wrong with your answer. Just don't beg for responses in comments. Let the system do its thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right...
try to use this:

```
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
```

instead of this:

```
grid-template-columns: 196px 196px;
```

so images will be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

The images are not being responsively sized because you have restricted the grid cells to a height of 196px. Since you use absolute length units like `px` for the `grid-template-columns` declaration, this is why they aren't resizing. They are simply occupying all of the grid items space like expected. You could use relative length units like `%`, `vw`, etc or `repeat(minmax())` in your column definition to fix this.

To make the images "scale with the viewport" or create a responsive grid that has grid items with dynamically determined dimensions, I tend to reach for [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()) paired with [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()). Allowing the images to occupy the parent grid item and grow/shrink with it. You just need to tweak your `grid-template-columns` usage. You could solely use `50% 50%` for your columns to make them scale with the viewport or use the `repeat()` usage I've defined below with a `max-width` on the parent grid.

```css
.imgContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; /* Using relative length units */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(14rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 80ch;
}

.imgContainer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="imgContainer">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="cat photo" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="cat photo" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="cat photo" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="cat photo" /></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @isherwood Was hoping to provide as much detail as possible and verify if it indeed helped the OP since my explanation differed a bit, didn't intend to "beg" or come off that way. I apologize and will make sure to stray away from doing that going forward :)